# Oracle Dates Where Time in Between Time Span

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a query that selects everything that is within a certain date range, e.g., between 2022-01-01 and 2022-12-31. This can be accomplished with the following query:

```
SELECT IMPORT_START FROM PROTOCOLS
WHERE IMPORT_START >= DATE '2022-01-01' AND IMPORT_START <= DATE '2022-12-31'
```

The `IMPORT_START` field also has a time portion. Now I need to further filter the results where the time is between 10pm and 7am. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT IMPORT_START
FROM   PROTOCOLS
WHERE  IMPORT_START >= DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    IMPORT_START <  DATE '2023-01-01'
AND    (  IMPORT_START <= TRUNC(IMPORT_START) + INTERVAL '7' HOUR
       OR IMPORT_START >= TRUNC(IMPORT_START) + INTERVAL '22' HOUR )
```

*Note: Use `< DATE '2023-01-01'` for the upper bound to get values up to `2022-12-31 23:59:59` otherwise you are limiting the range to `2022-12-31 00:00:00`.*

Answer (score -1):

Use the EXTRACT function to get the hours from IMPORT_START and then check if that value is >= 10 or <= 7

Comment: This will get values on or after 10:00:00 (not 22:00:00) and on or before 07:59:59 (not 07:00:00).